# Copy by value a DataGridViewRow?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a command class that (hopefully) uses a DataGridViewRow as a member in order to execute and undo. When I attempt to assign the incoming dgvr to the member row in the constructor (e.g. _row = r;), it appears I'm getting a reference, and not a new copy, making the undo operation impossible (the original dgvr gets deleted by then and the member row becomes empty).

I've also tried to "copy" the row via msdn as below:

```
public DataGridViewRow CloneWithValues(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    DataGridViewRow clonedRow = (DataGridViewRow)row.Clone();
    for (Int32 index = 0; index < row.Cells.Count; index++)
    {
        clonedRow.Cells[index].Value = row.Cells[index].Value;
    }
    return clonedRow;
}
```

This, however, seems to be leaving the schema behind, as I can't access the fields by name (e.g. _row.Cells["critical"].Value).

How do I make a copy by value of a DataGridViewRow?

Comment: Wouldn't you get the schema at the DataGridView level? If you are intending to use the cloned row in a different DataGridView object, I feel that DataGridView object would have the schema when you make it as a Cloned copy of the original DataGridView object.

Comment: I've found a nasty workaround for the time being: just make the row invisible rather than removing it after completing the udpate. This leaves the data in place in case an undo is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woul try a much simpler way, at the datatable level, call datatable.Rows.Add and pass your modified datarow.ItemArray.

This works if you still have a reference to your table which should be the grid datasource I think. I used this in my projects and usually worked fine.

Comment: I might have to refactor as you suggest. I was using the DataGridView for user selections of rows to update (gave them a checkbox). I'd then loop through the dgv and update based on the checked boxes. Am I correct in thinking that now I will have to update the DataTable to include rows only selected by the user and then loop through the DataTable?

Comment: Your answer worked. I passed the DataTable.Row.ItemArray into a new Object[]. Apart from some casting issues, it worked just fine.